# Динамическая полоса прокрутки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу добавить в header на сайт красивую горизонтальную полосу прокрутки, которая двигается одновременно с обычной полосой прокрутки в браузере. Отправьте, пожалуйста, ссылочки с реализацией, иначе найти никак не удалось.

Comment: https://only-to-top.ru/ - вот как здесь

Comment: Я бы попробовал отслеживать позицию скрола, и взависимости от положения добавлял или убирал стиль с полоски.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть целое видео как это делать правильно. [Держи, целый видео урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2u_BGkqFL8)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)